# Sublime Text 2/3 : editing opening and closing HTML tag shortcut (Mac)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

I just saw that one Sublime Text user recommends using `Cmd+Shift+k` while cursor is on any HTML tag to edit both the opening and closing tag type.

I can't make it work.

This shortcut doesn't seems to be built-in as there is no such keyboard shortcut defined in the Sublime Text default keymap file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There are several answers [here](http://superuser.com/questions/489879/edit-both-opening-and-closing-html-tag)

Comment: Thank you Beta. I wish I saw the thread when searching for one answer. I used the words in the question headlines... Weird.